# Android app crashes when connecting to webservice in local 500 Internal Server Error?

Tags: java, android, web-services, webservice-client, exchangewebservices

I can´t solve this, I got a problem connecting to my webservice from an Android client. In my MainActivity class the program crashes at the line 75:

```
transporte.call(accionSoap, sobre);
```

I think that the problem could be something with the accionSoap, any help would be very apreciatted.

Web Service:

```
package org.webapp.ws;

public class Hello {
 public String sayHello(String name) {
    return "Hello !!! " + name;
 }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.ejemplosoap;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//Napespace definido en el servicio web
private final String namespace = "http://ws.webapp.org/";
//Fichero de definicion del servicio web
private final String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/WebServiceServer/services/Hello";
//namespace + metodo
private final String accionSoap = "http://ws.webapp.org/sayHello";
//Metodo que queremos ejecutar en el servicio web
private final String Metodo = "sayHello";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
return true;
}

public void onClickLogin(View view){

new ServiceCallTask().execute();
}

class ServiceCallTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {

        System.out.println("1");
        // Modelo el request
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespace, Metodo);
        //request.addProperty("name", "Juan!"); // Paso parametros al WS
        PropertyInfo primerParametro = new PropertyInfo ();
        System.out.println("2");
        primerParametro.setName("name");
        primerParametro.setValue("Juan");
        request.addProperty(primerParametro);
        System.out.println("3");
        // Modelo el Sobre
        SoapSerializationEnvelope sobre = new              SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        //si esta hecho o no en puntoNet
        sobre.dotNet = false;
        sobre.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        System.out.println("4");

        // Modelo el transporte
        HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(url);
        System.out.println("5");

        // Llamada
        transporte.call(accionSoap, sobre);
        System.out.println("6");

        // Resultado
        SoapPrimitive resultado = (SoapPrimitive) sobre.getResponse();
        String cadenaDevuelta =(String) sobre.getResponse();
        Log.i("Resultado", cadenaDevuelta);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "ERROR");
                e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}


}



}
```

LogCat:

```
10-17 15:46:23.466: W/Trace(747): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-17 15:46:23.486: W/Trace(747): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-17 15:46:23.497: W/Trace(747): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-17 15:46:23.497: W/Trace(747): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-17 15:46:23.497: W/Trace(747): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-17 15:46:23.506: W/Trace(747): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-17 15:46:23.506: W/Trace(747): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-17 15:46:23.506: W/Trace(747): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-17 15:46:23.526: W/Trace(747): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-17 15:46:23.526: W/Trace(747): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-17 15:46:23.556: I/System.out(747): 1
10-17 15:46:23.556: I/System.out(747): 2
10-17 15:46:23.566: I/System.out(747): 3
10-17 15:46:23.566: I/System.out(747): 4
10-17 15:46:23.566: I/System.out(747): 5
10-17 15:46:23.566: W/Trace(747): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-17 15:46:23.566: W/Trace(747): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-17 15:46:23.617: D/dalvikvm(747): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 309K, 16% free 2601K/3068K, paused 35ms, total 35ms
10-17 15:46:23.617: W/Trace(747): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-17 15:46:23.626: W/Trace(747): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
10-17 15:46:23.845: E/MainActivity(747): ERROR
10-17 15:46:23.845: W/System.err(747): java.io.IOException: HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 500
10-17 15:46:23.865: W/System.err(747):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:195)
10-17 15:46:23.865: W/System.err(747):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:116)
10-17 15:46:23.875: W/System.err(747):  at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:111)
10-17 15:46:23.875: W/System.err(747):  at com.example.ejemplosoap.MainActivity$ServiceCallTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:75)
10-17 15:46:23.885: W/System.err(747):  at com.example.ejemplosoap.MainActivity$ServiceCallTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
10-17 15:46:23.885: W/System.err(747):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-17 15:46:23.885: W/System.err(747):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
10-17 15:46:23.895: W/System.err(747):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-17 15:46:23.905: W/System.err(747):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
10-17 15:46:23.905: W/System.err(747):  at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
10-17 15:46:23.905: W/System.err(747):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Thank you!

Comment: `HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 500` Your server told it to crash.

Comment: My server is very simple, it only returns Hello + param

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android app crashes when connecting IN LOCAL to webservice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19428866/android-app-crashes-when-connecting-in-local-to-webservice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to remove forward slash at the end of namespace namespace = "http://ws.webapp.org"

Comment: Yes! Now I have a problem here: SoapPrimitive resultado = (SoapPrimitive) sobre.getResponse();    java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive cannot be cast to java.lang.String   Any help?

Comment: Change that to Object, since you are returning a string

Comment: Change what? I am sorry I don´t understand, I am quite new... ;)

Comment: Change type SoapPrimitive to Object and cast Object to string.

Comment: The same, can´t cast this Object to String

Comment: Any other idea? Thanks!

Comment: Can you update your code so i can see what you have changed? Since your old code has these 2 lines which is strange
SoapPrimitive resultado = (SoapPrimitive) sobre.getResponse();
        String cadenaDevuelta =(String) sobre.getResponse();
Take out the String cadenaDevuelta = (String) sobre.getResponse();
Change SoapPrimitive to Object resultdado = (Object)sobre.getResponse(). From here you know how to cast to string

Comment: Done!! SoapPrimitive.toString() :D Thank you very much for your help!